# Parse powershell script parameters

Tags: powershell

Is there an easy way to parse the params from a powershell script file

```
param(
    [string]$name,
    [string]$template
)
```

I have started reading the file and wondered if there is a better way, maybe by a help/man command?

```
class PowerShellParameter {
    public string Name;
    public string Type;
    public string Default;
}

string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
bool inparamblock = false;
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++) {
    if (lines[i].Contains("param")) {
        inparamblock = true;
    } else if (inparamblock) {
        new PowerShellParameter(...)
        if (lines[i].Contains(")")) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least two possibilies. First one (imho better): use `Get-Command`:

```
# my test file
@'
param(
  $p1,
  $p2
)

write-host $p1 $p2
'@ | Set-content -path $env:temp\sotest.ps1
(Get-Command $env:temp\sotest.ps1).parameters.keys
```

For all members look at

```
Get-Command $env:temp\sotest.ps1 | gm
#or
Get-Command $env:temp\sotest.ps1 | fl *
```

The other (harder way) is to use regular expression

```
[regex]::Matches((Get-Help $env:temp\sotest.ps1), '(?<=\[\[-)[\w]+') | select -exp Value
```

Answer (score 3):

I like the solution with `Get-Command` proposed by @stej. Unfortunately it does not work if script parameters have explicit types specified and an assembly of such a type is not yet loaded into the session. That is why I still use this script: [Get names of script parameters](http://nightroman.wordpress.com/2008/10/16/get-names-of-script-parameters/)

Comment: +1 i'll have to look into System.Management.Automation.PSParser.Tokenize

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you're after, is it documenting your scripts? In that case have a look at `Get-Help about_Comment_Based_Help`. It will tell you how to do that, and after that you can use `Get-Help` on your script/module.

If you're after more strict parameter handling, take a look at `about_functions_advanced_parameters` and `about_functions_cmdletbindings` on how to better structure parameters. For example,

> `[Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage='Enter
>   architecture("OSX","WinXP","Win7","Linux")')]
>   [ValidateSet("OSX","WinXP","Win7","Linux")]
>   [string]$architecture`

will make that parameter mandatory, read from position 0 of the command, allow only a value from the given set, and give a brief help message when asking for input if that parameter was not given.